# How do I store array of objects in React using useState()?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and building a CV application form.

I'm having trouble storing the value in the form to an object in an array. It's weird because it seems to work for the undefined variables but not for the location variable, which is defined.

I assume I can keep an object in one state. In other words, I don't have to have separate states for each form input.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function EducationInfo() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState([]);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    console.log(`${name}: ${value}`);
  };

  const addEducation = () => {
    const educationNew = {
      school: school.value, // 'school' is undefined, red squiggly line in vsCode
      degree: degree.value, // 'degree' is undefined, red squiggly line in vsCode
      startDate: startDate.value, // 'startDate' is undefined, red squiggly line in vsCode
      endDate: endDate.value, // 'endDate' is undefined, red squiggly line in vsCode
      location: location.value, // actual variable but undefined when saving to array.
    };

    setInput([...input, educationNew]);
  };
  console.log(input);

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault}>
        <h2>Experience</h2>
        <div className='experienceContainer'>
          <label htmlFor='school'>School</label>
          <input type='text' name='school' id='school' onChange={onChange} />
          <label htmlFor='degree'>Degree</label>
          <input type='text' name='degree' id='degree' onChange={onChange} />
          <div className='dateContainer'>
            <label htmlFor='startDate'>Start Date</label>
            <input type='date' name='startDate' id='startDate' onChange={onChange} />
            <label htmlFor='endDate'>End Date</label>
            <input type='date' name='endDate' id='endDate' onChange={onChange} />
          </div>
          <label htmlFor='location'>Location</label>
          <input type='text' name='location' id='location' onChange={onChange} />
        </div>
        <button
          className='SubmitBtn'
          type='button'
          onClick={addEducation}
          onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault}
        >
          Save
        </button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default EducationInfo;
```

VS code:

[image: my code]

This is what the console shows me after I click the save button:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

use a different name for location like locate. value
I think it will work.
[image]

Comment: oh so it's using `windows.location()`. Do you know why the other values are undefined though, yet the code still works? Maybe I'm supposed to pass in props.

Comment: is it working ?

Comment: hey if it has helped you may be you could vote my answer..

Comment: Changing the variable name works. But I don't think it's correct since the red underline gives undefined.